# Remove empty last line from string (output from pipe)

Tags: python, string, pipe

I like to remove the empty line after my output:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

os.system("find /home/pi/bsp/musik/musik/ -name ""*.mp3"" | shuf -n 1 > /home/pi/bsp/musik/musik/track")
```

I get:

```
>>>cat track
/home/pi/bsp/musik/musik/2/Little Green Bag - George Baker Selection - Reservoir Dogs.mp3
```

But when I print the file in Python it's a different story:

```
>>>sudo python play.py
/home/pi/bsp/musik/musik/2/Lilly Allen - Fuck You.mp3

>>>>
```

...with a extra line in the end.

I like to pass a track to OMXPlayer, but with the additional line at the end there is no way...so I thought it can´t be to hard to get rid of it:

I tried to save a to a new file and remove the empty line with:

```
os.system("sed '/^$/d' /home/pi/bsp/musik/track > /home/pi/bsp/musik/tt")
os.system("mv /home/pi/bsp/musik/tt /home/pi/bsp/musik/track ")
```

Or remove it right in the pipe with:

```
sed '/^$/d'
```

Or remove it from the sting with:

```
text = os.linesep.join([s for s in text.splitlines() if s])
```

Or:

```
track[:track.rfind('\n')]
```

And after all nothing worked so far.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried passing it to omxplayer anyway? It's likely not a problem.

Comment: Pipe the output to `head -n -1`

Comment: Try [rstrip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `play.py` is `print`ing the contents of the file, the extra line at the end is coming from the `print` statement. If you need to output the contents of the file with Python, you can use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`, or `rstrip('\n')` the string, or put a comma at the end of the print statement, or use the print function with `end=''`. If you're directing input to OMXPlayer with shell redirection or something like that, it'll probably work fine without any extra effort.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(file_contents)
```

or

```
print file_contents.rstrip('\n')
```

or

```
print file_contents,
```

or

```
from __future__ import print_function

print(file_contents, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = track.rstrip()
```

> "Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. If
>   chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed."